# Was I right in making this answer community wiki?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

I have recently answered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724409/limit-of-a-succession-of-euler/3724419#3724419) question, which according to MSE guidelines, would be considered a poorly phrased problem. Have I made the right decision in answering the question community-wiki style? Should this be followed for providing hints to all poorly phrased problems on MSE?

Comment: Giving an answer in any form (including comments) encourages this kind of question. I doubt the OP knows what a "community wiki" answer is, and likely doesn't care whether or not you gain reputation for your answer.

Comment: @user1729 I am totally against providing complete solutions to poor quality questions. One or two hints should suffice. I didn't mind if the OP knows or not what a community wiki is. I was thinking that such poor questions should not be exploited for easy gain of rep. I believe that is frowned upon here.